# Random indices from masked array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D MaskedArray `X` and I want to randomly select 30 non-masked elements from it and return their indices `idx`.

The goal is that I could use the indices to read / set values efficiently later in my code:

```
selected = X[idx]
X[idx] = a # some arrays with the same length
```

What is the most efficient way of generating `idx`?

Comment: Ok and what have you tried?

Comment: I was able to generate a list of indices from a flattened array with masked values removed, `idx = np.random.choice(X.count(), size=30)`, but I have no idea how to map that back to indices from the original array

Answer (score 2):

Ok I have figured out a way... if anyone has a better approach please let me know.

```
pos = np.random.choice(X.count(), size=30)
idx = tuple(np.take((~X.mask).nonzero(), pos, axis=1))
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar task, by passing true/false of the array mask as weights to `np.random.choice`:

```
import numpy.ma as ma
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[0,0,0,1],[0,1,3,2],[2,0,0,3],[0,3,4,1]])
numSample=2

masked = ma.masked_where(data<3, data)
weights=~masked.mask + 0 #Assign False = 0, True = 1
normalized = weights.ravel()/float(weights.sum())
    
index=np.random.choice(
    masked.size, 
    size=numSample, 
    replace=False, 
    p=normalized
)        
idx, idy = np.unravel_index(index, data.shape)
```